# Rmarkdown produces double-spaced table of contents

Tags: r-markdown, knitr

Knitting a file to pdf using either `rmarkdown` 2.9 or 2.9.1 on xubuntu 20.04 with texlive installed generates a double-spaced table of contents. However, running `pdflatex` on the intermediate tex file converts the toc to single-spaced. Running `pandoc` on `test.Rmd` from the command line also creates a single-spaced toc.

To dup: Knit the file `test.Rmd` to pdf (`Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('test.Rmd')"`):

- `test.Rmd`:

```r
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    toc: true
    keep_tex: true
    number_sections: true
toccolor: 'red'
---
# Chapter 1
## subchapter 1.1
### subsubchapter 1.1.1
## subchapter 1.2
## subchapter 1.3
# Chapter 2
```

- Result from knitting:
  [image]
- Result from running `pdflatex test.tex` (the intermediate file created by `rmarkdown`) or `pandoc -f markdown --to latex --toc -o test.pdf test.Rmd`.

[image]

I think this is new behavior and I don't understand why it happens. Why would running `pandoc` generate a differently-spaced toc than `rmarkdown`, given that `rmarkdown` is just running `pandoc`?

Comment: Hm, I cannot reproduce your behaviour of `rmarkdown::render`. As far as I know, the current version of `rmarkdown` is 2.9: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmarkdown/index.html (and this is what I'm using; on Windows). Are you sure you're using `rmarkdown` 2.9.1?

Comment: @CL, Yes, I should have clarified that the problem originally occurred with 2.9 (the CRAN version) and I installed 2.9.1 from github (as requested by the maintainers for all problem reports) to be sure the issue persisted. I've edited the question to provide more details.

Comment: There is now a thread about this on github: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/2172